# what is a bookish game

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence Especially the bold part?

> From interactive sessions with authors to launches in digital and audio formats, and **bookish games to cover unveiling**, publishers are gearing up to celebrate World Book Day on April 23 amid lockdown.

[To read full article](https://www.thehindu.com/books/world-book-day-cover-audio-book-launches-digital-sessions-planned-amid-lockdown/article31411630.ece)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a definition of all the senses of [**bookish**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bookish):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a** : of or relating to books
>   **1 b** : fond of books and reading
>   **2 a** : inclined to rely on book knowledge
>   **2 b** *of words* : literary and formal as opposed to colloquial and informal
>   **2 c** : given to literary or scholarly pursuits
>   *also* : affectedly learned

The term *bookish game* refers to a game related to any of those senses of the word. For instance, I would consider *Trivial Pursuits* to be a bookish game. Or anything that involves spelling or grammar. Or something that depends on knowledge of literature.

Since the context of the quote in the question is books in particular, I would say that it's talking about a game whose subject is trivia centred around books. For example, I would expect "name the author of this quote" type questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard such a phrase.

Did you note that the phrase is repeated later in the article?   "In addition, it [Hatchett] will also partner with bookstores like Kitab Khana and The Bookshop to host giveaways on social media like playing **bookish games** with readers online and talking with bloggers who will talk about their favourite books."

From context, I would guess that it means playing games online with readers (possible customers), and that the games will be on the subject of books.

As to the rest of the sentence, "to cover unveiling", it sounds as if that means that the events will "cover", or provide publicity for, the unveiling of new books.

Comment: I think "cover unveiling" means "showing the designs of covers for new books for the first time" ie I think "cover" is a noun here.

Comment: @James K Maybe so.